# Two different ad unit IDs in one application

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I am not sure in admob policies. Is it against admob or Google Play policies, if I use two different  ad unit ID's - one my for interstitial ad and for banner the second ad unit ID of my friend? The app is developed by me and my friend. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't mentioned anything related to this in documents. It will work without any issue. I think two different types of ads (like admob, startapp) will not allowed by Google.

Check ads policy in below link.

https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html